# What's happened with the user name and why does this user have two 'Code Golf' accounts?

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

There is a user on ru.SO named Danis. Today, his chat messages have been renamed as if they belonged to someone named "a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae". If I click on the user's link "a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae", I see *two* linked *[Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour)* accounts with Danis code and "a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae". What it is???

> [image: what is it]

Link:

- [a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/478875/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae)